# Not getting prompted for certificate in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, certificate

I am unable to connect to a local intranet server using IE8.  This server issues an unsigned certificate.

When using IE8, it returns "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" instead of "there is a problem with this website's security certificate" like it's supposed to.  When using other browsers, including IE9, it prompts you to continue with the untrusted certificate.

I've checked my browser settings and no setting should be blocking this.  I am prompted for about certificates for other servers just fine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What do you mean its an **unsigned** certificate a certificate has to be signed, its either self-signed or signed by a organization you trust but its still signed.

Comment: At the end of the IE8 is not secure you really should think about trying to retire it from your network.

Comment: It is self-signed.  Unfortunately that decision is not up to me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that IE8 and the server simply have no shared ciphers (IE8 is missing lots of the newer ciphers), the server enforces TLS1.2 (which IE8 does not support) or that the server requires SNI (server name indication, used for multiple certificates behind the same IP address) which IE8 does not support.